# How to get a value from LevelDb in Go by a key ending?

Tags: database, go, nosql, leveldb

I know that it's possible to get values from LevelDb in Go by only a key prefix. However, I can't find any information about getting a value by key ending (key suffix). Is it even possible? If it is, how to implement it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as keys stored sorted by the beginning of key. So you would have to create new keys reversed to the original or modified in any other way so that you could iterate them by the prefix.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You mean storing two same pieces of date by different keys?

Comment: basically yes or come up with some other data modeling, but the fact is the keys are looked up / iterated by alphabetical order and you have to adapt to that